# Calling 2013 Designer Workflow from a 2013 Designer Workflow

Tags: 2013, rest, designer-workflow

I noticed that we cannot call a 2013 designer WF from within a 2013 designer WF. Can a workflow be called using rest api. If so are there any examples on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the workflow from code. I have a custom .aspx and in there I called a 2013 WF via a button.

Here how I start the workflow:

```
$("#anmelden"+id).click(function(e) {       
  startWorkflow(id);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And here the function:

```
function startWorkflow(itemID) {

        //alert("go for it");

        var subID = "5a7f927a-3137-47e8-85d7-39f03f85521d";
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();

        // Get Current User         
        var loginName = "";
        var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;     
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";       
        var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };

        $.ajax({
          url : requestUri,
          contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
          headers : requestHeaders,
          success : onSuccessA,
          error : onErrorA
        });


        function onSuccessA(data, request){

            var loginName = data.d.Title;

            //alert("Currently logged in: " + loginName);
            if (loginName != ""){

                var wfServiceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);

                var subscription = wfServiceManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);

                context.load(subscription);

                context.executeQueryAsync(
                    function(sender, args){
                        console.log("Subscription load success. Attempting to start workflow.");        
                        var inputParameters = {};

                        wfServiceManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemID, inputParameters);

                        context.executeQueryAsync(
                            function(sender, args){ 
                            console.log("Successfully starting workflow.");     
                            location.reload();
                            },
                            function(sender, args){ 
                                console.log("Failed to start workflow.");
                                console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function(sender,args){
                        console.log("Failed to load subscription.");
                        console.log("Error: " + args.get_message() + "\n" + args.get_stackTrace());
                    }
                ); 
            }

            else{
                alert("Error");
            }

        }

        function onErrorA(error) {

          alert(error);
        }       
    }
```

The variable `subID` is the ID of your workflow. You can get it if you go to your published workflows and copy the link of the workflow button.

If it is a SharePoint 2013 Workflow you should get a URL similar to this:

```
javascript:StartWorkflow4('5a7f927a-3137-47e8-85d7-39f03f85521d', '15', '{74AC618F-3714-43B8-90AB-349EA4F6D8DB}')
```

As you see the first part starting with 5a7... is the ID you need.

Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: :) Thank you @Patrick. This is good to know, but I am looking for a SP designer solution. Thanks again.